# All but everything; I have nothing to lose

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> Six letters long
>   Guess if you choose
>   I am all but everything
>   I have nothing to lose

Hint #1

> I am used to mean one of two things: one lies within this world, and the other is beyond.

Hint #2

> I’m not a zero or ‘absent’ per se, but my presence indicates absence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are :

> Vacuum

Six letters long

> Yes

I am all but everything

> Things are not in a vacuum

I have nothing to lose

> Vacuum has nothing

Hint #1

> Can refer to "Vacuum Cleaner" (in this world), or the vacuum of space (beyond this world)

Hint #2

> "Vacuum" indicates absence of anything

Answer (score 4):

**Second attempt**

I think you are

> Naught

Six letters long

> Naught is six letters long

Guess if you choose
I am all but everything

> Naught means nothing which is all but everything

I have nothing to lose

> Naught is nothing so it has nothing to lose.

**Original attempt**

I think you are a

> Shadow

Six letters long

> Shadow has six letters

Guess if you choose
I am all but everything

> A shadow is produced by an absence of light rays falling on a surface. It shows an object specifically by the obstruction of light produced by that object.

I have nothing to lose

> A shadow in itself is just darkness (the absence of light) so it is literally made of nothing.

Comment: Nice attempt (+1), but you still need an object and a light source to produce it.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Thanks, I have updated my answer.

Comment: So close! I’ve added a hint to bring you even closer.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Except

Six letters long

> ✔️

Guess if you choose
I am all but everything

> ✔️ Since you're an exception.

I have nothing to lose

> ✔️ Indeed, [except to make our lives into a work of art.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/688646-we-have-nothing-to-lose-nothing-to-gain-nothing-we)

Comment: Nice try, but it just doesn't fit into to the clues too well. However, rot13(ekprcgvba) would've got it if it weren't for it's length.